# Setting an AlpineJS data string in a function from outside of the component without using arrays or objects

Tags: javascript, global-variables, alpine.js

How do I get to update a alpine string variable from a function outside of the component ?

```html
<script>     
let global_status = 'IDLE';
const contactServer = (global_status) =>
{
    global_status = "PROCESSING";
}
</script>     
<div x-data="{ status: global_status }">
    <button x-on:click="contactServer(status)">CLICK</button>
    <p>
        Status :
        <span x-text="status"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Because this works if I set it to as as an array.

```html
<script>     
let global_status = ['IDLE'];
const contactServer = (global_status) =>
{
    global_status[0] = "PROCESSING";
}
</script>     
<div x-data="{ status: global_status }">
    <button x-on:click="contactServer(status)">CLICK</button>
    <p>
        Status :
        <span x-text="status[0]"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Alpine.js API to mutate a data object, otherwise it will lose its reactivity. For this kind of problem the simplest solution is to use the [global `Alpine.store()` object](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) that is easily accessible externally as well. You can mutate a variable inside a store object directly, or you can define an API inside the store to mutate the data. See the live example below:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
const contactServer = () => {
    // Mutate state directly:
    Alpine.store('global_status').status = "PROCESSING...";
    
    // Mutate state using API defined in the store object
    setTimeout(() => {Alpine.store('global_status').idle()}, 1000)
}

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('global_status', {
        status: 'IDLE',
        processing() {
            this.status = 'PROCESSING'
        },
        idle() {
            this.status = 'IDLE'
        }        
    })
})
</script>

<div x-data="{}">
  <button x-on:click="contactServer()">Contact server</button>
  <p>
      Status :
      <span x-text="$store.global_status.status"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```